# Point domain to RestLet web service?

Tags: windows-server-2003, windows-server-2008, iis, web-server

So, Lets say I have a Windows 2k3 server which has IIS. Lets say the address is 100.50.25.12. Now, lets say I have my stand alone RestLet webservice listening on port 1234. To hit this service externally, I can simply point to 100.50.25.12:1234. However, lets say I would rather hit my web service using services.my-domain.com and have that forward onto 100.50.25.12:1234. How would I configure this in IIS?

I think a host header setup would work, where I would just point services.my-domain.com (port 80) to localhost:1234 and it should forward my request onto my stand alone app, correct? I was under the impression that host headers would only work with websites in IIS, but I don't think this is the case? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for is called a reverse proxy. This isn't something that is built into IIS6, so you need to get a third party module to perform this function. [Managed Fusion URL Rewriter](http://urlrewriter.codeplex.com/) has this capability.

Since you added the Windows 2008 tag on there, I'll talk about IIS7 as well. You could still use the Managed Fusion product - but a better option would be to get the [Application Request Routing](http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/489/using-the-application-request-routing-module/) module and use that as a [reverse proxy](http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/659/reverse-proxy-with-url-rewrite-v2-and-application-request-routing/).

Another option would be to move your IIS site to a different port as well, and use a dedicated reverse proxy server, such as [nginx](http://nginx.org/), in front of both your IIS site and your RestLet service.

Comment: Would this also be something that my domain name provider (say, GoDaddy) could do instead?  Thanks for the response

Comment: If all they are DNS services, then I don't think there is anything they can do. (They just tell the world that services.my-domain.com = 100.50.25.12 - no port information at that level.) - if you can get another IP/hostname though, then they could - you would have IIS listen on 1 ip, RestLet listen on the other (both on port 80) and then you could have services.my-domain.com point to IIS and restlet.my-domain.com point to the RestLet service.

Comment: Thanks for the info!  I'll have to dig and figure this out when I have the time, but this answer looks right.